# $x() always returns ƒ (){} in Chrome Developer Tools console on gmail page

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, gmail

`$x("//div")` always returns ƒ (){} in Chrome Developer Tools console on gmail page.

For that matter it returns empty function for any locator.

Whereas same locator `$x("//div")` on a jira page correctly returns array of all divs.

```
Chrome 73.0.3683.103 MacOS 10.14.3 Mojave
```

Any clues?

BTW, this locator is just used for testing since the actual locator was failing from Python 3.x based Selenium scripts using chromedriver.
So redefining of $x() affects Selenium automation too?

[image: gmail divs]
[image: jira divs]

Comment: Share your HTML in plain text format. Expected outcome and actual outcome.

Comment: @cruisepandey Can you please login in to your gmail account and try that expression in Chrome Dev Tools Console? I am curious to know what you get. Thx.

Comment: I get `undefined` with chrome 73.0.3683.103 on macos.

Comment: This means that Gmail has redefined `$x`.

Comment: @Barmar but works as expected on a jira page in another browser tab.

Comment: That means that Jira has NOT redefined it.

Comment: Ah, I assumed Google chrome redefined it!

Comment: No, it's redefined in one of the JavaScript files loaded by mail.google.com.

Comment: @Barmar Edited question with this information. "BTW, this locator is just used for testing since the actual locator was failing from Python 3.x based Selenium scripts using chromedriver.
So redefining of $x() affects Selenium automation too?
"

Comment: `$x` is not a standard JavaScript function, it's just a convenience function for debugging in Chrome or Firebug. I doubt Google really cares that they overrode this.

Comment: You may want to try using `document.evaluate('//div', document)` instead which isn't overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$x(thePath, [startNode])` is a convenience function wrapping over [`document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) - it calls it as `document.evaluate(thePath, startNode, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)`, where `startNode` is `document` by default.
The browsers have chosen to implement it **only in the console**, the same way they have implemented `$()` and `$$()` wrappers over `document.querySelectorAll()` - for devs convince.

And looks like the developers of Gmail have chosen to override it :). So just use the normal/basis function to execute the xpath elements search:

```
document.evaluate("//div", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
```